# How to access data of an array within an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to write a program that can parameterize shapes/objects detected on a sequence of images in Python and I'm having a serious brainfart.

I'm at the stage now where I have an array with each element containing another sub-array which holds the information I need.

So for a sequence of 5 images, the array looks like this in the variable explorer

**`MainArray:`**

`0: Subarray 1: [object 1]`
`1: Subarray 2: [object 1], [object 2]`
`2: Subarray 3: [object 1], [object 2], [object 3]`
`3: Subarray 4: [object 1], [object 2], [object 3], [object 4]`
`4: Subarray 5: [object 1], [object 2], [object 3], [object 4]`

Each object is another array that contains more data such as it's area and position, the objects do not change throughout the sequence when added to the subarray

**Question: I want to get the area for the first object in each subarray to plot on a graph, how would I do it?**

So far I am sure the solution is to create a loop, but right now, I'm having trouble figuring out how to write the loop

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what does the `object` look like inside of the array.

Another way of iterating nested arrays without loop is to do a recursion. Here is an example,

```py
def iterate_arrays(arr):
    for item in arr:
        if isinstance(item, list):  # if the item is a list, call the function recursively
            iterate_arrays(item)
        else:
            print(item)  # if the item is not a list, just print it (or do whatever you want)

nested_array = [1, [2, 3], [[4, 5], [6, 7, [8, 9, [10]]]]]
iterate_arrays(nested_array)
```